# Android emulator and voice recognition

Tags: android, android-emulator, microphone

I use the android 2.2 sdk under Windows Vista and I'm trying to get audio from the microphone using plug on my computer. I try example from [this tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/), but each time my application is stopped by android emulator.

Is it possible to use `AudioRecord` with microphone in the emulator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472370/why-is-it-impossible-to-use-the-speech-recorder-on-the-android-emulator